# How do I call my horse using keyboard and mouse?

Tags: pc, red-dead-redemption-2

In the first chapter, in the hunt deers mission, the game shows how to call your horse so you don't have to walk up to it. I forgot the control for that command using keyboard and mouse. Searching online I could only find instructions on how to call your horse with a gamepad.

Looking at the key mapping options, I did not find a key for "call horse", I tried different action keys with no success. How can I call my horse? Do I need a certain level of bonding before being able to call my horse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this article](https://guides.gamepressure.com/red-dead-redemption-2/guide.asp?ID=52400), the default mapping is **H**, but this can be changed in the settings.